# Disable “Automatically Acquire Lock and Activate Changes” in WLS Admin Console

Tags: python, oracle, weblogic, jython, wlst

how can I deactivate (uncheck) the checkbox `Automatically Acquire Lock and Activate Changes` in WLS Admin Console?

I am aware I could do it via Preferences but I would defintely prefer doing it with `wlst`, rather than having manual interactions.

The goal is to get rid of this

[image: message]

and release the configuration afterwards.

[it is a development environment and I am doing a automated domain setup and enterprise application installation]

Comment: what exactly, you are trying and what is the error you facing ?

Comment: I don't have errors. Basically what I do is; (all automated)

 - create a new domain out of a template
 - start the domain 
 - deploy an Enterprise Application

the deployment of the Enterprise Application is not working, because the `Automatically Acquire Lock and Activate Changes` option is active hence the domain cannot be locked/unlocked as normal.

I want to deactivate the checkbox with using WLST and not with manual interactions over the WebLogic Console because everything else is fully automated

Comment: that is what I want to do, but automated @Ravi
[link](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WLACH/taskhelp/console/EnableAndDisableTheConfigurationLock.html)

Comment: All console's preferences are stored in a file inside your domain : ${DOMAIN_HOME}/servers/AdminServer/data/console/ConsolePreferences.xml
You can write a wlst script that will update this file to meet your needs.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin thanks a ton! That helped and is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution based on @EmmanuelCollin's input:

Open the configration file:

`vi ${DOMAIN_HOME}/servers/AdminServer/data/console/ConsolePrefe‌​rences.xml`

And edit the following XML Tag as shown below:

```
<preference name="implicitactivation" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value="false"/> <!-- Acquire Lock and Activate Changes. Set to "false" to disable checkbox -->
```